# Using key of a dictionary on another dictionary crashes

Tags: swift

Following code fails with an error on xcode playground. Couldn't understand the reason why. This was tried in XCode 9.3.

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on line `if (value as! String) != (dictionary[key] as! String) {`. Here key is x, dictionary[key] is nil, whereas the dictionary has a key with x.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

extension Dictionary {
    func isSubDictionary(of dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Bool {
        var fail = false
        outerloop: for (key, value) in self {
            switch value {
            case is Int:
                if (value as! Int) != (dictionary[key] as! Int) {
                    fail = true
                    break outerloop
                }
            case is Double:
                if (value as! Double) != (dictionary[key] as! Double) {
                    fail = true
                    break outerloop
                }
            case is String:
                if (value as! String) != (dictionary[key] as! String) {
                    fail = true
                    break outerloop
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        return !fail
    }
}

let v: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["x": "y"]
let u: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["x": "y", "z": "u"]

print("\(v.isSubDictionary(of: u))\n")
```

Comment: On this line: `if (value as! String) != (dictionary[key] as! String)`, `dictionary[key]` might not exist.

Comment: For the variables that I have passed as params to the function, it should not crash @Larme

Comment: Did you try to debug? That could be interesting to show what crashed, and what you don't understand. Like adding `print("dictionary: \(dictionary)"); print("value: \(value)"); print("key: \(key)")`

Comment: Seems like some problem while converting the Dictionary's 'Key' type to the required type. when I tried '(value as! String) != (dictionary[key as! String] as! String)' it seemed to work...

Comment: I understand if let, guard let, this method is used in a unit test case code, I don't mind even if it crashes while unwrapping. For the parameters that I have passed, this should not crash whereas it is crashing which seems a weird issue. @Moritz

Comment: @Moritz I've tried debugging, have updated the question with the line it crashes & the key that it holds in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added `isSubDictionary` as an extension to Dictionary, so the type of `self` is `Dictionary<Key, Value>`, not `Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>`. This means that the keys of `self` and of `dictionary` are not the same.

A value of type `AnyHashable` hides, but still knows, the type is it wrapping. When you write:

```
dictionary[key]
```

`key` is wrapped in an `AnyHashable` but the type that is being wrapped is `Key`. So when it is used as a key to `dictionary`, the wrapped type `Key` does not match the wrapped types in this second dictionary’s keys. You can see this with:

```
print("\(dictionary.keys.contains(self.keys.first!))") // prints false
```

If your intent is that the two dictionaries are of the same type, then make the function:

```
func isSubDictionary(of dictionary: [Key: Any]) -> Bool
```

Comment: Of course if he does that, he can get rid of the whole `switch`. You might want to point that out!

Comment: You are right and I changed the value type back to `Any`.

Comment: Changing the code to `extension Dictionary where Key == AnyHashable {
func isSubDictionary(of dictionary: [Key: Any]) -> Bool {` got it working